# SQL sorting with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements

I have a table with players. The admin wants to sort the players by a condition. If column `activerank = 1` then the player adds to sorting else if `activerank = 2` the player should be shown at the end of players. How can I do this?

Here is my query, without this condition:

```
$sql = '
  SELECT c.*
  FROM `child` AS c
  WHERE  '
  c.`id` > 0
  ' ORDER BY c.`rank` DESC ';
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the player should be shown at the end of players`?

Comment: You can use CASE statement.

Comment: Wouldn't you just sort by activerank, anotherfield_you_are_sorting_on - since all the 2's would be at the end.

Comment: the player to be still visible for all users, but in last position. Players with rank > 0 must showing in fist position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use additional sorting first order by activerank Ascending

```
  SELECT c.*
  FROM `child` AS c
  WHERE  '
  c.`id` > 0
  ' ORDER BY activerank ASC,  c.`rank` DESC '
```

in this query players with `activerank = 1` will be first and will be sorted among them according to rank and players with `activerank = 2` will be last

For more advanced sorting I recommend to use [CASE CLAUSE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add `CASE WHEN` in `ORDER BY`, and use multiple `ORDER BY`

```
 SELECT c.*
  FROM `child` AS c
  WHERE  'c.`id` > 0' 
  ORDER BY c.`rank` DESC,
   (
   CASE activerank 
        WHEN 1 THEN 0
        WHEN 2 THEN 1 
   END
   )
```